# formik access initialValues in onSubmit handler for comparison with values

Tags: reactjs, graphql, formik

I have an edit form which uses Formik. I need to upload a new image if the picture string has changed. I need to compare the **initialValues** of the picture field vs the **values** of the picture field to determine whether to call the fileUpload function to upload a picture and return the string uri

How can i access the initialValues in my onSubmit handler in order to do this comparison. I have been searching online and found an [article](https://medium.com/@MelkorNemesis/how-to-check-if-formik-values-have-changed-on-submit-2c6ee89992ec) on this topic, however, the author is using redux and recompose. In my case, I am using graphql and am not using any state management libraries

Is it possible to still do such a comparison without a state management library? n how can i access initialValues inside my onSubmit handler?

formProps has both initialValues and values. submitProps only have values but doesn't have initialValues which I need to make a comparison if the field has been changed by the user

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    ...getMusicById,
  }}
  onSubmit={(values, bag, ...submitProps) => {
    console.log("@onSubmit ", values, bag, submitProps);
    const {
      session: { me }
    } = this.props;
    this._handleSubmit(values, bag, me);
  }}
  validationSchema={formValidateSchema}
  render={({ isValid, isSubmitting, ...formProps }) => {
    console.log("@formProps ", formProps);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to still do such a comparison without a state management library? n how can i access initialValues inside my onSubmit handler?

Not directly - simplicity of ready components (`<Formik/>`) always has drawbacks.

**You can use any state management method and pass values for `initialValues` as props.**

In article `<Formik/>` is embeded into `<FooForm/>` enhanced with HOC's. Values are stored in redux and passed as props into `<Formik />`

You can use simple class component and it's state (or props) to be passed down as `initialValues`. Submit handler defined in the same component (passed as prop, too) will have access to data/object in `this.state`. Of course you can use hooks - `useState` for this in functional component.

You can use `withFormik` HOC - `props.initialValues` should be available.

Comment: Thanks @xadm for confirming this and sharing the various ways i can access the initialValues.